# Material UI - outlined button - "Unexpected use of 'self' no-restricted-globals"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use an outlined button from material UI : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/buttons/OutlinedButtons.js

But get the error - "Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals"

And I don't have permissions to change it in the lodash.throttle/index.js file.

Is there any workaround for this that anyone knows of?? (It's literally just the sample code btw)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '../node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '../node_modules/@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
    button: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    },
    input: {
        display: 'none',
    },
});

function OutlinedButtons(props) {
    const {classes} = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button}>
                Default
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}


OutlinedButtons.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(OutlinedButtons);
```

After a request. App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import   UserGroup   from './components/user_group';
import ButtonTest from './components/Button';
import OutlinedButtons from './components/floatingButton'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                { OutlinedButtons }

            </header>
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Can you add more of your code, leading up to the `ReactDOM.render()` call? From a bit of Googling, the `Unexpected use of 'self'` error seems related to the `window`.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a build system error. I just built it with Parcel, without any problems.

Comment: @JasonWarta interesting. What could cause it? Im just using a create-react script

Comment: @ReedDunkle done

Comment: I tried it with CRA right now and it works. Why do you use relative path import for material-ui? Also why don't you use your component as `<OutlinedButtons />`but instead you use it as expression `{OutlinedButtons}?`

Comment: @devserkan are those things the source of the problem?

Comment: Which version of material-ui are you using? Some of your imports suggest you might be mixing version 1.0.0 with 0.20.1.  Specifically, MuiThemeProvider shouldn't be importable from the path you've specified.  The correct path (for 1.0) should be `'@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider'`

Comment: @MiahThompson could be. First, fix the import part as explained in the above comment or in the documentation then use your component as `<OutlinedButtons />`. Then see what happens.

Comment: yeah @devserkan that didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Which one did not work? After trying to render your Component what happened. Is the error same?

Comment: @devserkan after making your changes yes it was the same.

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent version of material-ui, and fix your MuiThemeProvider import statement per my previous comment.

Comment: @JasonWarta I added it and removed the old 'material-ui' but got : 

'__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Listen to @JasonWarta's suggestion. Be sure to use latest version of material-ui. Here is a simple working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/j4384xp45y